# Angular Material slide toggle component is null by default

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am building an Angular app in which I am using the `md-slide-toggle` component in my form validation.

On the `onSubmit` method, when I log the value to the console, it logs null by default. How do I assign the `md-toggle-slide`'s value to be false by default?

```html
<form #formtest="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formtest.value)">

    <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let temp of value">
    <md-slide-toggle [checked]="isChecked" color="primary" name={{temp}} ngModel> {{temp}}</md-slide-toggle>
    </div>
    <button md-raised-button type="submit">Check</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: P.S. Consider not combining `ngModel` and `name` together. Instead, either use just `ngModel`, or use Angular Reactive Forms: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `app.component.ts`, import [`OnInit`](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#oninit) from `@angular/core`, then add the [`ngOnInit` lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#oninit) with methods, declarations and whatever else you have to initialize on load.

**app.component.ts**:

```ts
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
// Your other imports here

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: '/path/to/app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    checked: boolean;
// NgOnInit is required or else Angular will throw an error
    ngOnInit() {
        this.checked = false;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, initially assign the property a value:

```ts
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
// Your other imports here

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: '/path/to/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    checked: boolean = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be solved by the following simple way of creating a variable in your component file:

```ts
public value = [
  {name:'one', checked:false},
  {name:'two', checked:false},
  {name:'three', checked:false}
];
```

And bind them to the component using the following HTML code:

```html
<form #formtest="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formtest.value)">

    <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let temp of value">
    <md-slide-toggle color="primary" [name]="temp.name" [(ngModel)]="temp.checked">{{temp.name}}</md-slide-toggle>
    </div>
    <button md-raised-button type="submit">Check</button>
</form>
```